# Sql Select Issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows-phone-7

Hello i need some help with this query. Im trying to SELECT all of the messages that belongs to two users using their UserId. I want to return a variable to know if the CurrentUserId is the Receiver or the Sender of each message.

---

**Table structure:**

Table name: *Messages*

Column names:

- SenderUserId (The Id of the User who sent the message)
- ReceiverUserId (The Id of the User the message was sent to)
- Message (Holds the message)
- SentDate (When the message was sent)

---

**Example of expected output:**

Message---------------------------
SentDate
------------------------------FromMe

---

Hello User--------------------------23:45, 16/2/2012----------------------True----

---

**Query right now:**

```
SELECT Message, SentDate FROM Messages 
WHERE SenderUserId=@CurrentUser AND ReceiverUserId=@OtherUser 
OR SenderUserId=@CurrentUser AND ReceiverUserId=@OtherUser
```

So what i basically want to do is that i want to return all of the messages that these users has been sending to each other, i also want to know with an boolean if the @CurrentUser is the sender of the Receiver of each message. True if the message was sent from the @CurrentUser and False if the message was sent by the @OtherUser.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT Message, SentDate ,
CASE 
  WHEN SenderUserId=@CurrentUser THEN 'True'
  ELSE 'False'
END as is_sent_by_current_user
FROM Messages  
WHERE (SenderUserId=@CurrentUser AND ReceiverUserId=@OtherUser ) 
OR (ReceiverUserId=@CurrentUser AND SenderUserId=@OtherUser)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
SELECT Message, SentDate,case when SenderUserId = @CurrentUser then 'true' else 'false' end as sentByYou FROM Messages 
WHERE (SenderUserId=@CurrentUser AND ReceiverUserId=@OtherUser) 
OR (SenderUserId=@OtherUser AND ReceiverUserId=@CurrentUser)
```

Comment: Sorry I read your message wrong,  look at @a1ex07 answer.  That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use stored procedure to get data from SQL I would suggest getting the data you need and then doing all necessary checks in code begind. By doing this all your rules and calculations will be in 1 place (BLL ideally).

Hope it helps.